# How to remove space (line) between expanded block

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I use three expanded block. When i wrap container with expanded, space/line is show.
I can't remove it between Expanded block. Although I have used many ways. 

Has anyone encountered the same case yet? Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtbTE.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     home: Scaffold(
     backgroundColor:  Color(0x000000),
     body: Container(
      color: Color(0x000000),
      child: SizedBox.expand(
        child: VariousDiscs(),
      ),
    ),
   ),
 ),
);
}

class VariousDiscs extends StatelessWidget {

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Expanded Column Sample'),
    ),
    body: Center(
     child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0xbf000000),
          height: 100,
          width: 100
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0xbf000000),
        height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0xbf000000),

          height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ),
      ),
     ],
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: There is no space between blocks as in my system. https://dartpad.dev/0d7e5cef17d5add51bad5996722d3ebd

Comment: @Dev could you please post a screenshot? because I could reproduce it on DartPad

Comment: Thanks. Image in dart pad in here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtbTE.png

Answer (score 0):

### Update on 2020-02-26:

Seems like this got fixed on the latest version of flutter.

---

I have tested your code on an Android device with the stable release of the Flutter and it works fine without any issue.

But I could [reproduce](https://dartpad.dev/f743d1bf23a742b06819cfc7c07142d4) the issue on Flutter DartPad, and the screenshot you have shared is taken from the DartPad and it seems like this issue is related to the DartPad or flutter web version.  You may open a bug report on the dart pad [repo](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad).

Comment: Thanks. I have tested in iphone x without any issue. But in small screen device as iphone 5, 6 and it it seems like this issue.